# Using a .mat file for a EMG signal in Google Colab

Tags: python, matlab, import

Hi I'm getting troubles with a .mat file that was recorded with Matlab. The errors come when i try to use te matplotlib and scipy.io libraries. I'm using the code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sp

emg = sp.loadmat('/content/myosigs30.mat')
time = np.array([i/1000 for i in range(0, len(emg), 1)])
plt.plot(time,emg)
plt.show()
```

and then just get an empty graph and a error message as shown in picture [ErrorColab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7Gc3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for me it looks that you have one row and one column vector. Please debug your code - first check size of emg and time - they must be equal.

Note: if len() returns you an array, not a single number it means you have 2d(or more) matrix which you might have to reshape / extract specific data to be plotted

Comment: Thanks I solved it by creating a directory an then an array :D Your answer was very helpful.